# JavaScript tabbed folders don't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

They work just fine in firefox. I'm a newbie web developer and I got this code from a manual. I need the tabs to work for my university project. Please look at the link below for the code and result.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzysmtih/XnUSH/)

Comment: What doesn't work? Any error messages?

Comment: None, just says error on page when I click a tab. Actually I've tested it again and it doesn't work in FF either. The folders don't appear according to the clicked tabs.

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't work at all in Firefox. *edit* actually it does, but the content is positioned strangely.  Did you just copy/paste that from a blog or something?

Comment: No it was code from a web design book. It was published a couple of years ago now.

Comment: it actually seems to work in IE as well if its not run from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, that jFiddle did not work at all for me (in Chrome, at least), I had to move it locally to even begin to get things to work...

I got this to work in Internet explorer 9 by removing / commenting out the following line

```
oldTab.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
```

That solves that problem, but leaves you with another one, which you can tackle :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- content above snipped -->
<div id="Folder3" class="folder"
style="position:absolute; left:70px; top:470px; width:500px; height:300px; z-index:3; visibility:hidden; overflow:auto">
<h1>ewrwer</h1>
<p>xvxcvvdf</p>
</div>

<!-- jsfiddle shows me that this closing div tag is extraneous -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that one too. When I removed it (both in jsfiddle and locally) it didn't seem to change anything, though.